# How to store application configurations on the server?

Tags: asp.net, .net, github, deployment, continuous-integration

It is not allowed to store client specific secrets into config files of .NET applications and then commit these to GitHub.

We would like to do it so, that config files are always present on the server, and we only deploy the bin folder, which then references these files in a different location.

MSdeploy has a setting for not touching files on the server that were created there. We would prefer it if we could keep deleting extra files on the server on every deploy (because, not doing this can show broken behaviours as working) and hence would like to place the config files on a separate level from the application.

The configSource attribute does not allow you to refer to files that are below the root level of the application, so my question is - is there any good approaches to config management in a case like this? Symlinks is a possible solution here, but afaik, these also create a physical file on disk which would get deleted by MSDeploy

Generally this question revolves around github and client secret management, so any pointers to that topic generally are also appreciated.

For context, we are trying to have a fully geo-distributed set of teams working on the same codebase, and the environments that we deploy to are all over the place. We do not want any secrets in github, and want to nail reliability when it comes to continuously integrating these changes into the various test environments.

Comment: What are you using for your build agent? I use Team City, and what I have done in the past is to have a build step perform these types of steps.

Comment: We are currently using Jenkins. What we do is use MSbuild to transform configs specific to the environment before we deploy. Currently we have to switch to github, so we can't have these transform configs in there anymore, and that's the reason we're looking into changing the model.

Comment: So are your servers that you are deploying to statefull like a Hosted VM or Stateless like a Docker? If it is statefull I would use a Environment Variable for these config values. If it is stateless you still may be able to do that depending on the technology.

Comment: Currently, stateful hosted VMs. I'll look into environment variables as an option. Thanks.